# Dota 2 Compendium 2016 battle pass: Items are marketable?

Tags: dota-2

As you can see there is new battle pass **Compendium 2016** for **Dota 2** in market with so many new immortals and items. I have read full battle page but did not get that items from compendium is trade-able/marketable or we have to wait for months like in other compendium(M asking as in last compendium items were trade-able) but not sure this time so please help me.

I am asking this question as if they are trade able then i can buy pass with 50 level or i will go with normal one. Hope this is a generic question which won't get negative votes. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for bothering but i have got the answer. They are **not trade-able/marketable till 14 Aug 2016**. I came to know after buying battle pass and by opening the treasure. There is description under item that item will be trade-able after 14th Aug 2016. Hope it will help others. Thank you

Comment: PS Ultra-rare items that drops from treasures are marketable.

Comment: @htzfun yup i came to know after seeing void's immortal in market. Thank you